# one way MANOVA post hoc?

Tags: post-hoc, manova

I am currently doing a one-way MANOVA with one independent variable- 2 levels and two dependent variables. I have a repeated measures design and I am not sure what post hoc test to use.

Comment: what are your hypotheses ? And objective of your study ,

Comment: Indicate your data / results ?